# Error in ROS: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface

Tags: ros

I am getting this error:

> [WARN] [1549645986.850056, 54.996000]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface

while launching a **urdf** in **gazebo**. I am using **ROS Kinetic** and have looked for a solution for this error everywhere but couldn't find it. A similar question is asked [*here*](https://answers.ros.org/question/214712/gazebo-controller-spawner-warning/). I have done everything suggested in that link and the `libjoint_state_controller.so` file is present at `opt/ros/kinetic/lib.` I have added the gazebo plugin in my `.xacro` file.

```
<gazebo>
 <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
  <robotNamespace>/mushak</robotNamespace>
  <robotParam>/mushak/robot_description</robotParam>
 </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

This is the `.launch` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
 <group ns="/mushak"> 
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find mushak_pkg)/urdf/mushak_model.xacro'" />
  <arg name="x" default="0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0.2412"/>

  <!-- Spawn the robot model -->
  <node name="mybot_spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen"
      args="-urdf -param robot_description -model mushak -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z)" />

  <!-- Load controllers -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mushak_pkg)/config/config.yaml" />

  <!-- Controllers -->

  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner"
    respawn="false" output="screen" ns="/mushak"
    args="
    joint_state_controller
    joint1_position_controller
    joint2_position_controller
    joint3_position_controller
    joint4_position_controller
    joint5_position_controller
    joint6_position_controller
    --timeout 50
    ">
  </node>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
      <remap from="/joint_states" to="/mushak/joint_states" />
  </node>

 </group>

</launch>
```

The model is opening in rviz without any error. The following is the output when I run `rospack find joint_state_controller` .

> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/joint_state_controller

Also, in the terminal in which the Gazebo is running the following error is shown:

> [ERROR] [1550681387.800721476, 9.313000000]: GazeboRosControlPlugin missing  while using DefaultRobotHWSim, defaults to true.
>   This setting assumes you have an old package with an old implementation of DefaultRobotHWSim, where the robotNamespace is disregarded and absolute paths are used instead.
>   If you do not want to fix this issue in an old package just set  to true.

I have added the transmissions  to all the joints:

```
   <transmission name="trans_${name}">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="${name}">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_${name}">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
```

Can someone help me with this please!